# Replacing a setInterval timer in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I've got an animation with a specific speed which value is being passed from an input range. When the page loads the animation default speed is 16, as you can see below.

HTML:

```
 <input type="range" min="1" max="30"   /><br>
```

JS:

```
  animateInterval = setInterval(animate, 16);
    $("input").change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
   animateInterval = setInterval(animate,  value);
    })
```

Whenever I choose a new speed via the input range slider, the variable number with which I want the animation speed to run at, isn't replacing the default speed, it's actually adding to the default speed. So when the page loads and it runs at 16, and I decide to drag the slider to 10, the animation doesn't run at 10, it runs at 26! This doesn't allow me to slow down the animation, nor does it let me decide my own max speed as it can constantly be incremented.

How would I need to adjust the above code so that the speed clocks at whatever value is chosen, despite having the requirement for having a default speed when the page is loaded?

Comment: Use `clearInterval` on the first value of `animateInterval` before assigning the result of another `setInterval` call to your variable.

Comment: You might need to cancel (clearInterval(animateInterval)), then reset your interval with the new delay.

Comment: Always impresses me how almost identical answers can be given a few seconds apart  ; )

Comment: If you want to regulate speed of animation then probably your approach is not correct. Number 16 doesn't set the animation speed, but it sets refreshing rate. Your animation (for which the code you didn't provide) should depend on time, and there is the right place to control the speed of animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clear the previous interval before setting a new one:

```
clearInterval(animateInterval);
```

What you are doing now is setting yet another interval every time and all fire in parallel.

Comment: I love it when the answer is able to be given using a single line of code. It worked like a charm. Thank you.