# How to update JSON query / data after new user input?

Tags: javascript, json, user-input, json-query

I'm creating a weather dashboard that updates every 5 seconds. I would like the user to be able to change the target city, and have the dashboard update with the new data.
Problem is every time they input a new city, the previous data stays and it seems to be looping through all the inputs the user has made so far.

I would like the data to be updated after the user inputs a new city, rather than added. This is my code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    const api_key = "c7eedc2fa8594d69aa6122025212904";
    const inputCity = document.getElementById("inputCity");
    const getCity = document.querySelector("form");

    getCity.addEventListener("submit", e => {
        // Prevent the form from submission
        e.preventDefault();
        var inputVal = inputCity.value;
        var api_url = "http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=" + api_key + "&q=" + inputVal + "&days=3&aqi=no&alerts=no";
        // Get the dataset
        function refreshData() {
            fetch(api_url).then(response => {
                response.json().then(json => {
                        var dataset = json;
                        var output = formatResponse(dataset);
                    })
                    // Catch error - for example, the user doesn't input a valid city / postcode / country
                    .catch(error => console.log("not ok")); // TO BE IMPROVED
            })

        }

        refreshData(); // Display the dashboard immediately

        setInterval(refreshData, 5000); // And then refresh the dashboard every X milliseconds


    });

    function formatResponse(dataset) {

        console.log(dataset);

        // Current temp
        var currentTemp = [dataset.current.temp_c];
        console.log(currentTemp);
        document.getElementById("currentTempDsp").innerHTML = currentTemp + "°";

        // Current state icon
        var currentIcon = [dataset.current.condition.icon];
        console.log(currentIcon);
        document.getElementById("iconDsp").src = "http://" + currentIcon;

        // Current state text
        var currentText = [dataset.current.condition.text];
        console.log(currentText[0]);
        document.getElementById("currentStateDsp").innerHTML = currentText;

    }


}
```

```html
        <form id="getCity" class="search">
            <label id="labelCity">Search for a city...</label></br>
            <input type="text" id="inputCity" class="inputCity" placeholder="Type city name here...">
            <button id="submitCity" type="submit" class="submitCity"><i class="fas fa-search"></i>Submit</button>
        </form>
            <div class="state">
                <h2 id="currentTempDsp"></h2>
                <img id="iconDsp"/>
                <span id="currentStateDsp"></span>
            </div>

        </div>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: You’ll have to store a reference to the current interval in a variable, then clear out with `clearInterval()` before setting a new one.

Comment: Duplicate of [Replacing a setInterval timer in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37260781/replacing-a-setinterval-timer-in-js)

Comment: @esqew Thank you, I had tried doing that, but it doesn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about *why* the answers in the linked duplicate didn't meet your requirements (error messages, expected vs. actual behavior)?

Comment: @esqew It didn't change anything, as in I'm having the same problem. I stored the set interval in a variable (interval) and added clearInterval(interval); everywhere in the submit event listener, but nothing. Could you provide some code with how you would do it?

Comment: When you stored the return value of `setInterval()` in a variable, was its value properly scoped (globally, outside the event handling function)?

Comment: @esqew I tried that now, but it's telling me that refreshData() is not defined so the dashboard isnt updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an interval using `setInterval()` it continues to execute until the page is reloaded, navigated away from, or explicitly cleared using `clearInterval()`. Simply setting more intervals will not stop any previous ones from firing.

Use a globally-scoped variable to store the return value of `setInterval()` - check if it's set in the beginning of your submit event handler and clear it if it is.

A simplified example of how you could get this done:

```js
const locations = [{
  temp: 73,
  conditions: 'Sunny'
}, {
  temp: 22,
  conditions: 'Mostly Cloudy'
}];

var currentInterval = null;

const updateTemp = locationData => {
  document.querySelector(".number").innerText = locationData.temp;
  document.querySelector(".conditions").innerText = locationData.conditions;
  console.log(`updated interface with temperature (${locationData.temp}) and conditions (${locationData.conditions}) data`);
}

[...document.querySelectorAll('.add-location')].forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // clear the interval
    if (currentInterval) {
      clearInterval(currentInterval);
      currentInterval = null;
      console.log('cleared currentInterval');
    }
    updateTemp(locations[parseInt(e.srcElement.dataset.loc)]);
    currentInterval = setInterval(function () {
      updateTemp(locations[parseInt(e.srcElement.dataset.loc)]);
    }, 2500);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.temp {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.conditions {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="temp">
  <span class="number">--</span>
  <span class="deg">&deg;</span>
</div>
<div class="conditions">--</div>
<div>
  <button class="add-location" data-loc="0">Add location 0</button>
  <button class="add-location" data-loc="1">Add location 1</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked!!!!!! Very smart / simple way of doing it. Wish I wasn't such a noob :D